# Private String in a second class

Tags: java

I have designed two classes. I need to call the format method of the `Card` class in order to get the Card holder + name in the `IDCard` class. When I try to compile it gives the error that *name has private access in card*, but I have a getter statement.

```
public class Card{
    private String name; 

    public Card() { 
        name = " "; 
    }

    public Card(String n) { 
        name = n; 
    } 

    public String getName() { 
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isExpired() { 
        return false;
    }

    public String format() { 
        return "Card holder: " + name; 
    } 
}
```

This is the second class:

```
public class IDCard extends Card { 
    private String idNumber;
    public IDCard (String n, String id) { 
        super (n);
        idNumber = id;
    }

    public String getId() { 
        return idNumber;
    }

    public String format() { 
        return name.format() + "\n" + "ID Number: " + idNumber; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be super.format() instead of name.format()

Answer (score 1):

Since name is `private` it cannot be accessed directly by its sub-classes.
So use the getter method to get the name:

```
return getName() + "\n" + "ID Number: " + idNumber;
```

Note that `String` does not have a zero argument `format` method. (so `name.format()` will generate a compilation error)

However you can use the super implementation and append with the current description:

```
return super.format() + "\n" + "ID Number: " + idNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `name.format()` to `getName().format()` or `super.format()`. You can't access private variable by calling it by name - you must use getters, if you don't want to have getters and access variables in subclasses (classes which extends other classes) change access modifier from private to protected. You should also add @Override annotation before your format() method.

Answer (score 0):

In `IDCard.format`, call `getName()`:

```
getName().format() + "\n" ....
```

`private` cannot be directly accessed from subclasses. 
BTW if you had made it `protected`, it would have bee accessible to subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Use your `getName()` for your inherited class to have access to name in the `Card` class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't use private fields from a class you extend in the child class. You need to use your getter method.

Answer (score 0):

You are making two mistakes actually:

1. You can't access `name` from `IDCard` directy, you should use its accessor `getName()`.
2. Even so, it wouldn't work, because `getName()` returns a String; what you may want to do, actually, is, in `IDCard`:

   ```
   public String format() { 
       return super.format() + "\n" + "ID Number: " + idNumber; 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the format method by using the super keyword?

```
super.format() + "\n" + "ID Number: " + idNumber;
```

Even if you have a getter method the field itself is private so you can't access it directly.

Answer (score -1):

Just make the `name` field `protected`. This keyword exists just for this purpose, and it's weird to call a getter method instead.

Comment: `protected` will also allow access to this field from other classes in same package. Getters seems better in this case.